# Justifying text input controls in table cells with different spans using CSS

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have a pretty basic question.

I am designing a form using HTML and CSS which should resize to the current page width (e.i. I have to use the relative units for all sizes). The form consists of several text fields all having different width and my client wants that they are arranged in a certain manner (like, for example, ZIP, City and Country to be three different fields in one row with different size proportions etc.).

To correctly layout the input fields along with their captions I put them into a table, using cells with different column span. I align the controls within `TD` with `float:left` and use relative width (like `width:90%`) to make the controls occupy the entire cell.

The problem I am facing is that my controls are aligned to the left and in the cells with different column spans the right margin looks jagged, i.e. all text input fields have slightly different width, because the cell have different widths and the size is proportional to cell width which may vary due to different `colspan` (see the picture).

[image: Jagged right border]

How can I make my controls to look aligned on both sides?

P.S.: I am a web developer with some knowledge of HTML and CSS, but I am not at all a designer. Thus, this question might be utterly basic for a designer, but I failed to find a plausible answer with reasonable keyword combinations. If it is a sort of common topic (that I suppose) please just provide me with some clues how to formulate my question in the way to find answers.

Comment: Don't use tables for controlling layouts. Here is a good place to start: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/prettyaccessibleforms

Comment: @Diodeus I would love to skip tables alltogether, but in the tutorial you reference the layout is just "vertical", i.e. one field per line. What I need is a really block design: several blocks with control elements in them with up to 3-4 text fields per line, with some external boxes showing grouping of similar elements etc. I don't see how I can use plain CSS to layout these elements: even if I use `inline` layout for input text fields, I can't get them in "optically" in one box.

Comment: Use DIV containers and floats.

Comment: @Diodeus As I said, I am not a designer. One more or less similar looking example with CSS would already do, but what I have seen so far done with `div` and CSS was too simple to render the design my client wants. It should really mimic a Windows desktop application in its look-and-feel (don't ask me why, this there is a whole usability team behind this layout).

Comment: Mac users will get a different experience - things like SELECT are rendered by the OS, not the browser. You'll be tweaking CSS padding, line-height and margins quite a bit to get this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i cant tell without your code but it looks like you may be using different font sizing for the input fields which i think could create the effect you are getting.
can you paste the css and html for the three elements you have shown in the pic?

Comment: You are correct with you guess that the font sizes are different: for some fields I use `1.2em` as font size. Should that be a problem for right margin? I will try to extract the CSS for these elements and update my answer as soon as I have access to this code.